# Haskell - Struggle understanding types

Tags: haskell, types, higher-order-functions

I am new to Haskell, but it was really fun until now. Currently I am working on understanding Types and Type Classes

Example: `add :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`. `->` is right associative which means the declaration is similar to `Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)`, so far so good. But what does `(a->b) -> a -> b` mean? Why do we use parenthesis suddenly? 
In my textbook there is an example for this declaration with a function `apply::(a->b)-> a->b` with the def. `apply f x = f x`. But I don't understand that, isn't `(a->b)` a single function?

I know that a and b are Typevariables which indicates that a and b are of different Types.

Comment: Parenthesis in the type declaration are used to tell that we are expecting a function as an argument (parenthesis have the highest precedence). In your example, if there were no parenthesis, it would be `a -> b -> a -> b` which you can read as a function taking 3 arguments and returning a value of type b. Where as `(a -> b) -> a -> b` would read as a function taking 2 arguments (a function and another value of type a, and returning a value of type b

Comment: "`a` and `b` are type variables which indicates that `a` and `b` ***may be*** of different types".

Comment: @WillNess That’s correct. `(a->b) -> (a->b)` is a higher order function, like `apply` that takes a function as its argument and returns a function that itself has type `(a->b)`. So, what is `apply f`? Why, it’s a function that takes an argument and applies `f` to it, and `f` has type `a->b`. So `apply f` is a function from type `a` to type `b`. Just as the type signature of `apply` says! That example is a bit contrived, but `(.)` and `map` are only slightly more complicated and very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you see parenthesis in the type signature you can think of it as one block. So `(a -> b) -> a -> b` is the same as `c -> a -> b` where `c` stands for `a -> b`. `c` just happens to be a type which is a function itself.

The same way your first example `Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)` was a function that takes an `Integer` and returns a function `Integer -> Integer`; your function `(a -> b) -> a -> b` is a function that takes as argument a function `a -> b` and an argument `a` in order to return a `b`.

In the case of this function `apply` it is simply function application. If `apply` is defined as `apply f x = f x` it simply passes argument `x` to the function `f`. By the way, this function already exists in the Prelude and is called `($)`.

Comment: the key thing is that "function of type `(a -> b) -> a -> b` is a function that takes as argument a function of type `a -> b` and *perhaps later* another argument of type `a` in order to return a `b` type value *then*" - so that while `apply f` hadn't yet received that `a` value, it is itself a function of type `a -> b`. i.e. `apply f :: a -> b`. That's why `(a -> b) -> a -> b` and `(a -> b) -> (a -> b)` are the same type.

Comment: I agree! +1 I didn't want to explain this in too much detail because I thought understanding that a function can be passed as an argument was the main road block for OP; not partial application or currying, which OP can get familiar with at a later point. :-)